# Jquery PHP media upload library

Tags: php, jquery

Strange trouble
I want to upload image via ajax which many plugin does but none support textarea to write caption. As i want to assign a caption to every image ,how do my new learning task makes it different is i want user to be able to put up caption whilst image is uploading.

Do any one know of such plugin that just donot send ajax request but also have text box requests attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to answer your question, I don't know of any such plugin.

However, all plugins should support custom parameters to send as GET or POST. Check the documentation.

If it doesn't, then it sucks. You can however mod it yourselt.

If it does, then it is a simple issue of fetching the textarea value and attaching it in one such parameter to be sent.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i would had given you +1 for this thought :)... but am at student level yet.Thanks for help

Comment: I really do not mind, but good way to never get an answer btw.